# In what way is ADHD genetic?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, psychology, health

According to [Psychcentral](http://psychcentral.com/news/2013/08/19/5-major-mental-illnesses-traced-to-same-genetic-variations/58642.html) depression, bipolar disorder, ADHD, schizophrenia and autism are traceable to the same inherited genetic variations

According to [AsapSCIENCE](https://youtu.be/GOK1tKFFIQI?t=98), depression could be genetic due to a variation in the serotonin transporter gene. Having at least one short seems to give some kind of genetic predisposition to depression.

So what's the analogue of the serotonin transporter gene in ADHD? Is there a dopamine transporter gene?

Double posted on Cognitive Sciences Stackexchange

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4264104/ The diagnosis is observational. One misconception that people have is that a given genotype will, in 100% of cases produce a phenotype. So even if the genetic marker(s) has(have) been identified, it doesn't mean that the expression patterns of a person will be such as to produce the phenotype.  There will be a predisposition, but it is possible that a heterozygote allele could rescue the normal phenotype. It is also possible that even homozygotes will not manifest the phenotype if the deleterious gene is not expressed.

Comment: @AMR For a lay person pls? 'There will be a predisposition' --> How? I'm guessing the serotonin transporter gene is what gives a predisposition for depression. What about for ADHD?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's cross posted and answered on CogSci.SE:http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/what-is-the-underlying-genetic-basis-for-adhd